# Apache crash - PHP

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

UPDATED INFO:

OS Windows 7 32bit
Apache 2.2.15
PHP 5.2.13

---

This is really weird. When I got to this URI in my application:

```
/view/course/teid/1/cid/-1/pos/30
```

Apache crashes.

When I go to a very similar URI - like this one:

```
/view/course/teid/1/cid/-1/pos/29
```

Everything works fine.

This is from error log:

```
[Thu Aug 05 11:22:14 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
```

I have been able to track down the line which causes the Apache to crash:

```
if (true === $aCourseTree->SetNodePassed($node)) { // this line crashes Apache
    self::writeTreeToDb($aCourseTree, $training, $this->aUtils);
}
```

The method is here:

```
public function SetNodePassed(CourseTreeNode $theNode)
{
    $aWasChange = !isset($theNode->Passed) || $theNode->Passed !== true;
    $theNode->Passed = true;

    if ($aWasChange && isset($theNode->Parent)) {
        if (true === $this->AreChildrenPassed($theNode->Parent)) {
            $this->SetNodePassed($theNode->Parent);
        }
    }
    return $aWasChange;
}
```

What the hell is going on? If there is some error, it should just be a PHP error. Why does Apache crash?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the next line that causes the problem - the one that starts `self::writeTreeToDB`?

Comment: No. If I comment that line, it still crashes. When I comment out the whole if condition but leave the static method uncommented, it works.

Comment: may be too many recursion is the cause... check the #theNode value and check for recursion condition

Comment: I have added my system information.

Comment: i did some google search ,so upgrade your php to 5.3 and apache to 2.3 ;ppl are saying that this did the trick for win 7.If not try to upgrade your libmysql.dll to newer version.

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy Where can I get the latest  libmysql.dll? Should I copy it to C:\Wnidows\System32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running PHP in your Apache?

`mod_php` can easily kill an Apache worker process[1], and the correct course of action for the Apache server as a whole is to try to return to as 'clean' a state as possible. It is nearly impossible for a process to clean up after corrupted memory, but restarting is very safe and easy.[2] It goes a long way towards returning the system to a known-good state.

You may wish to switch to a FastCGI implementation instead of `mod_php`; if you need more reasons, here's a very well-written set of reasons:

http://www.majordojo.com/2007/11/is-mod-php-falling-out-of-favor-with-hosting-providers.php

[1] The PHP team asked Linux distribution security teams to stop calling php-interpreter crash bugs "security problems" -- they fixed those sorts of bugs so often, that remotely-exploitable security bugs in php and its libraries were getting drowned out in the noise.

[2] Of course, to re-execute itself, it would need to call one of the `exec()` functions on memory that could possibly be corrupted, but hopefully the only corrupted memory in the master Apache process would be the scoreboard. So a re-exec should be safe enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this at the top of your php script and see what error are you getting

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```